# QApplication が２度目に必ずエラーを吐く現象について

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

```
from PySide import QtGui

import sys
class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Widget,self).__init__(parent=None)


def main():

    try:
        QtGui.QApplication([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(10,e)
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

これは何の変哲もない、`Widget`を表示するだけのプログラムです。
お聞きしたいのは、`QApplication`についてです。
`QApplication`は、最初はエラーなく実行されるのですが、
２回目からは、必ずエラーを吐きます。ウィジェットをクローズしても、
カーネルは、`QApplication()`が一度実行されたことを覚えていているようで、
カーネルを再起動しない限り、再度実行する事ができません。

追記：
そのため、try:except文でこのエラーを回避することにより、コードを実行しています。
もしこの文が無ければ、

```
A QApplication instance already exists.
```

と書かれた`RunTimeError`が発生します。

他の`Qt`ユーザーたちは、そういう事が無いように思うのですが、
このエラーが発生しない方法はありますか？
おもちの実行環境では、そのようなことはありませんか？
開発環境は　Anaconda3 Spyder3.2.4です。

Comment: 必ずエラーを吐くということであれば、そのエラーの内容も追記していただけると回答者の参考になると思います。

Comment: @tanalab2 了解です。

Comment: すみません。ググっただけになりますが、https://qiita.com/it_ks/items/449b7418e83956ecdc8c#qapplication が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: @tanalab2 正確な解答のようです。よろしければその旨で解答を書いていただけたらと思います。

Comment: さん 回答をついかしました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[【補完】[PySide] QtDesignerで遊ぼう](https://qiita.com/it_ks/items/449b7418e83956ecdc8c#qapplication)という記事に関連しそうな記載がありました。

記事によると、以下を実行すると`A QApplication instance already exists.`が発生するため、

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
# Error: A QApplication instance already exists.
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# RuntimeError: A QApplication instance already exists. #
```

以下のように修正する必要があるそうです。

```
app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
```

Comment: 長年ほっといた問題だけど何度も心に引っかかっていた事でした。ようやくつかえがとれました。ありがとうございました。